# FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1 Error Python

Tags: python, regex

I was working on something and at some point, I needed to check whether the string satisfies this:
The string must contain at least 5 words and each separated by a hyphen(-) or an underscore(_).
Here is the code that I wrote:

```
password=eval(input('Password:'))
pattern=r'[[\w][-_]]{5,}'
import re
re.fullmatch(pattern,password)
```

But it gives   ' ipython-input-32-7c87b09218f8>:4: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
re.fullmatch(pattern,password) ' error. Why that happens, any idea?Thanks in advance.Btw I'm using Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Why not write it like this repeating the word chars `\w+(?:[/_]\w+){4,}` and a single character class for `/` and `_`

Comment: Yeah it worked,thanks but what's the meaning of ?:[...] part?Can you explain it?

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `[[\w][/_]]` to mean in a regular expression? See how the warning mentions a "nested set"? If you consider that the *documentation for regular expressions* uses the term "character set" (or sometimes "character class") to mean something that you write inside `[]` in a regular expression, can you see how that relates to the regular expression that you have? (Notice how there are `[]` inside of `[]`? Does that make sense? What is the intended purpose?)

Comment: What do you think is the purpose of `[]` in a regular expression? How about other kinds of brackets, such as `()`? (Also: `/` is **not** a "hyphen".)

Comment: Yeah,it doesn't. I expected it to mean repeat  -one word and hyphen or underscore- pattern at least five times but as The fourth bird said it should've been (?:[/_]\w+),  I get it now,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match 1+ word characters, and then repeat at least 4 times matching either `_` or `/` and again 1 or more word characters.

```
\w+(?:[/_]\w+){4,}
```

**Explanation**

- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `[/_]` Character class matching either `/` or `_`
  - `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `){4,}` close the no capture group and repeat 4 or more times

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nObEvE/1).